# XGBoost: ValueError: feature_names must be unique

Tags: python, pandas, xgboost

I cant run my code, my all features are already unique but I take error as "ValueError: feature_names must be unique".
I read the forum and tried "brew install libomp" and other suggest but my code doesn't working yet, how can I solve that?

My feature names:
Index(['Cinsiyet', 'Kronik hastalık', 'Oral_Antibiyotik', 'Ateş', 'Oksuruk',
'Kusma/ Beslenmede bozulma', 'Solunum_Sıkıntısı',
'anormal solunum dinlem bulgusu', 'Hipoksi', 'yaş_ay', 'yatış_kg',
'Şikayet_Süresi', 'Oral_Antibiyotik', 'Ateş', 'Hemoglobın',
'lenfosit_sayısı', 'nötrofil_sayısı', 'Albumın', 'Sodyum', 'Ast'],
dtype='object')

Already unique.

Answer (score 2):

`Oral_Antibiyotik` is repeated twice

**EDIT:** `Ateş` too